# Swift Decodable pre-set field (from JSON)

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I have the following model:

```
struct User: Decodable {
  var user: String,
  var email: String,
  var selected: Bool = false
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
   "user":"foo",
   "email":"foo@bar.com"
}
```

When loading the JSON as data and decoding it to the User object, I get a failure. Because it's missing the key selected. However, I have supplied a default value in the User object itself. Is there an easy way to not include 'selected' in the parsing of the user json?

Eg this fails because one of the keys is missing

```
let obj: User = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.type, from: data)
```

(when the key is present in JSON it works, but I want to add some 'local' data to the user) (eg which user is selected by the person that uses the software).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify `CodingKeys`. All keys which are not in the enum are ignored.

```
struct User: Decodable {
  var user: String
  var email: String
  var selected: Bool = false

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case user, email }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom decoder:

```
struct User: Codable {
    let user: String
    let email: String
    let selected: Bool

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        user = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .user)
        email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)

        let decodedSelected = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .selected)
        selected = decodedSelected ?? false //  Here is the default value
    }
}
```

Also, you can use a property wrapper but it needs a lot more decoding codes. take a look at [this article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/default-decoding-values/) if you are interested

Comment: Yeah, was familiar with this one, but was curious if there was an easier way. And it seems there is now (see accepted answer).

Comment: @Matthijn hmmm I thought there is a chance to get `selected` from the server. If you know you will never get it, the accepted answer is enough.

Comment: You  were looking for **local** value not **default** value.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer based on Article (@propertyWrapper): https://www.programmersought.com/article/94997602083/**

```
protocol DefaultValue {
    associatedtype Value: Decodable
    static var defaultValue: Value { get }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Default<T: DefaultValue> {
    var wrappedValue: T.Value
}

extension Default: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        wrappedValue = (try? container.decode(T.Value.self)) ?? T.defaultValue
    }
}

extension KeyedDecodingContainer {
    func decode<T>(
        _ type: Default<T>.Type,
        forKey key: Key
    ) throws -> Default<T> where T: DefaultValue {
        try decodeIfPresent(type, forKey: key) ?? Default(wrappedValue: T.defaultValue)
    }
}

extension Bool {
    enum False: DefaultValue {
        static let defaultValue = false
    }
    enum True: DefaultValue {
        static let defaultValue = true
    }
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let user: String
    let email: String
    @Default<Bool.True> var selected: Bool // Default Value: true
}

/// Make Network Request
typealias RequestCompletionHandler<T: Decodable> = (_ value: T?, _ error: Error?) -> Void


func callAPI<T: Decodable>(completionHandler: RequestCompletionHandler<T>) {
    let data = """
{
   "user":"foo",
   "email":"foo@bar.com"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        completionHandler(value, nil)
    } catch {
        completionHandler(nil, error)
    }
}

callAPI { (model: User?, error) in
    if let finalModel = model {
        print("\(finalModel)")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```